# Shall I stop this update statement? been running for 9 hours

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-update

I am using SQL Server on Windows 10

I run an update statement on a table of 170M records

The SQL update is been running for more than 9 hours now and apparently needs another 24 hours!!

here is my SQL

```
declare @N int = 400000

declare @RT varchar(100) = 'Respiratory'

SELECT RepID into #R FROM reps where RepType =@RT
and RepID between @N and @N+2000000

if exists(select top 1 * from #R)
begin
    update T set RepType = @RT
    from Tags T inner join #R R on T.RepID = T.RepID
    where T.RepType is null
    and T.RepID between @N and @N+2000000
end

drop table #R
```

There is a Non clustered index on RepID.

here is the SQL plan

The Plan for the update

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.539" Build="15.0.2000.5" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="3" StatementEstRows="52808.7" StatementId="2" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="150" StatementSubTreeCost="80.6837" StatementText="SELECT RepID into #R FROM reps where RepType =@RT&#xD;&#xA;and RepID between @N and @N+2000000" StatementType="SELECT INTO" QueryHash="0xA0849F528C9329F2" QueryPlanHash="0x47415AE0C1F84948" RetrievedFromCache="true" SecurityPolicyApplied="false">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="12" MemoryGrant="200" CachedPlanSize="56" CompileTime="573" CompileCPU="1" CompileMemory="312">
            <ThreadStat Branches="1" UsedThreads="12">
              <ThreadReservation NodeId="0" ReservedThreads="12" />
            </ThreadStat>
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" RequiredMemory="200" DesiredMemory="200" RequestedMemory="200" GrantWaitTime="0" GrantedMemory="200" MaxUsedMemory="200" MaxQueryMemory="1576848" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="138610" EstimatedPagesCached="103958" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="6" MaxCompileMemory="6553896" />
            <OptimizerStatsUsage>
              <StatisticsInfo Database="[Recovery]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Reps]" Statistics="[_WA_Sys_00000006_2A4B4B5E]" ModificationCount="0" SamplingPercent="2.25627" LastUpdate="2021-06-07T15:49:22.12" />
            </OptimizerStatsUsage>
            <WaitStats>
              <Wait WaitType="LATCH_EX" WaitTimeMs="488333" WaitCount="2489" />
              <Wait WaitType="PAGEIOLATCH_SH" WaitTimeMs="73823" WaitCount="3119" />
              <Wait WaitType="MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT" WaitTimeMs="317" WaitCount="450961" />
              <Wait WaitType="PAGELATCH_SH" WaitTimeMs="17" WaitCount="106" />
              <Wait WaitType="CXPACKET" WaitTimeMs="13" WaitCount="13" />
              <Wait WaitType="LCK_M_S" WaitTimeMs="6" WaitCount="11" />
              <Wait WaitType="PAGELATCH_UP" WaitTimeMs="2" WaitCount="21" />
              <Wait WaitType="LCK_M_X" WaitTimeMs="2" WaitCount="2" />
              <Wait WaitType="SESSION_WAIT_STATS_CHILDREN" WaitTimeMs="1" WaitCount="10" />
            </WaitStats>
            <QueryTimeStats CpuTime="2472" ElapsedTime="47061" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="9" EstimateCPU="0.0395238" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="52808.7" LogicalOp="Gather Streams" NodeId="0" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Parallelism" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="80.6837">
              <OutputList />
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="26007" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="47060" ActualCPUms="2" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <Parallelism>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="9" EstimateCPU="0.00880145" EstimateIO="0.109432" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="52808.7" LogicalOp="Insert" NodeId="1" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Table Insert" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="80.6442">
                  <OutputList />
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="12" ActualRows="2122" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="47030" ActualCPUms="205" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="11" ActualRows="2198" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="46997" ActualCPUms="201" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="10" ActualRows="2113" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="46993" ActualCPUms="209" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="9" ActualRows="2208" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="46990" ActualCPUms="220" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="8" ActualRows="2076" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="47059" ActualCPUms="205" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="7" ActualRows="2135" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="47059" ActualCPUms="202" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="6" ActualRows="2398" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="46993" ActualCPUms="181" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="5" ActualRows="2163" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="46994" ActualCPUms="209" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="4" ActualRows="2067" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="46992" ActualCPUms="205" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="3" ActualRows="2141" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="46993" ActualCPUms="210" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="2" ActualRows="2084" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="46993" ActualCPUms="206" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="1" ActualRows="2302" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="46994" ActualCPUms="204" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="0" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="0" ActualCPUms="0" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <Update DMLRequestSort="false">
                    <Object Table="[#R]" Storage="RowStore" />
                    <SetPredicate>
                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[#R].[RepID] = [Recovery].[dbo].[Reps].[RepID]">
                        <ScalarExpressionList>
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <MultipleAssign>
                              <Assign>
                                <ColumnReference Table="[#R]" Column="RepID" />
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                  <Identifier>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[Recovery]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Reps]" Column="RepID" />
                                  </Identifier>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </Assign>
                            </MultipleAssign>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </ScalarExpressionList>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </SetPredicate>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="38" EstimateCPU="0.0628187" EstimateIO="80.4357" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="52808.7" EstimatedRowsRead="342505" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" NodeId="2" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="80.4985" TableCardinality="2084420">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Recovery]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Reps]" Column="RepID" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <RunTimeInformation>
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="12" ActualRows="2122" ActualRowsRead="140105" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="47022" ActualCPUms="203" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="47951" ActualPhysicalReads="2" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="11" ActualRows="2198" ActualRowsRead="140104" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="46988" ActualCPUms="200" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="47996" ActualPhysicalReads="1" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="10" ActualRows="2113" ActualRowsRead="141066" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="46975" ActualCPUms="207" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="48411" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="9" ActualRows="2208" ActualRowsRead="139485" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="46975" ActualCPUms="218" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="48402" ActualPhysicalReads="2" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="8" ActualRows="2076" ActualRowsRead="140950" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="47048" ActualCPUms="203" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="47887" ActualPhysicalReads="1" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="7" ActualRows="2135" ActualRowsRead="138523" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="47048" ActualCPUms="200" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="47414" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="6" ActualRows="2398" ActualRowsRead="141092" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="46975" ActualCPUms="179" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="48469" ActualPhysicalReads="2" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="5" ActualRows="2163" ActualRowsRead="141264" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="46975" ActualCPUms="207" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="48401" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="4" ActualRows="2067" ActualRowsRead="139185" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="46975" ActualCPUms="203" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="47953" ActualPhysicalReads="2" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="3" ActualRows="2141" ActualRowsRead="139800" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="46975" ActualCPUms="207" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="48402" ActualPhysicalReads="1" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="2" ActualRows="2084" ActualRowsRead="141291" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="46975" ActualCPUms="204" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="47955" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="1" ActualRows="2302" ActualRowsRead="141553" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="46975" ActualCPUms="202" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="48404" ActualPhysicalReads="1" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="0" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="0" ActualCPUms="0" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="5378" ActualPhysicalReads="1" ActualReadAheads="575295" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                      </RunTimeInformation>
                      <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[Recovery]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Reps]" Column="RepID" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <Object Database="[Recovery]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Reps]" Index="[PK_Reps]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                        <SeekPredicates>
                          <SeekPredicateNew>
                            <SeekKeys>
                              <StartRange ScanType="GE">
                                <RangeColumns>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[Recovery]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Reps]" Column="RepID" />
                                </RangeColumns>
                                <RangeExpressions>
                                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(bigint,[@N],0)">
                                    <Identifier>
                                      <ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1006">
                                        <ScalarOperator>
                                          <Convert DataType="bigint" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                                            <ScalarOperator>
                                              <Identifier>
                                                <ColumnReference Column="@N" />
                                              </Identifier>
                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                          </Convert>
                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                      </ColumnReference>
                                    </Identifier>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </RangeExpressions>
                              </StartRange>
                              <EndRange ScanType="LE">
                                <RangeColumns>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[Recovery]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Reps]" Column="RepID" />
                                </RangeColumns>
                                <RangeExpressions>
                                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(bigint,[@N]+(2000000),0)">
                                    <Identifier>
                                      <ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1007">
                                        <ScalarOperator>
                                          <Convert DataType="bigint" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                                            <ScalarOperator>
                                              <Arithmetic Operation="ADD">
                                                <ScalarOperator>
                                                  <Identifier>
                                                    <ColumnReference Column="@N" />
                                                  </Identifier>
                                                </ScalarOperator>
                                                <ScalarOperator>
                                                  <Const ConstValue="(2000000)" />
                                                </ScalarOperator>
                                              </Arithmetic>
                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                          </Convert>
                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                      </ColumnReference>
                                    </Identifier>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </RangeExpressions>
                              </EndRange>
                            </SeekKeys>
                          </SeekPredicateNew>
                        </SeekPredicates>
                        <Predicate>
                          <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Recovery].[dbo].[Reps].[RepType]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(100),[@RT],0)">
                            <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[Recovery]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Reps]" Column="RepType" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1005">
                                    <ScalarOperator>
                                      <Convert DataType="nvarchar" Length="200" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                                        <ScalarOperator>
                                          <Identifier>
                                            <ColumnReference Column="@RT" />
                                          </Identifier>
                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                      </Convert>
                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                  </ColumnReference>
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Compare>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </Predicate>
                      </IndexScan>
                    </RelOp>
                  </Update>
                </RelOp>
              </Parallelism>
            </RelOp>
            <ParameterList>
              <ColumnReference Column="@N" ParameterDataType="int" ParameterRuntimeValue="(400000)" />
              <ColumnReference Column="@RT" ParameterDataType="varchar(100)" ParameterRuntimeValue="'Respiratory'" />
            </ParameterList>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementId="1" StatementText="declare @N int = 400000&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;" StatementType="ASSIGN" RetrievedFromCache="true" />
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

[image]

Shall I kill this process and start over or keep it running? how to improve it?

Comment: How long does it normally (or how much time is it expected to) take to run?

Comment: Working with that many records should be done in batches/loops to avoid blocking from other processes and it is more manageable and easier to see progress where/how far along it is.

Comment: The temporary table `#r` won't have an index on it, which may be dragging down the performance.  Why use the temporary table?

Comment: @user2864740 I don't know. it is my first run

Comment: @Brad so what shall i do now?

Comment: That's not the full plan (it does not cover the update) so .. hard to give input. Anyway, I'd use a plan visualizer (SSMS or https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). If the 9 hours is only the insert to the temp table, something is horribly wrong with performance as it's a clustered read over only 2M rows. *Perhaps it is schema blocking and unable to generate the plan for the UPDATE?*

Comment: For what you should do that would depend on what/how you are using the data and what would be impacted if you stopped it.  If you stop it, it will cause a rollback (if you have that enabled) and rollbacks can sometime take longer than the processing it took until the rollback happened.  So in other words if it was running for 9 hours the rollback could take even longer than that, and I say could because there are a LOT of factors involved.  Just like there are a lot of factors with what could be causing it to take so long.

Comment: @user2864740 the copy to temp is completed long time ago. i updated the plan with the update plan

Comment: Can you update the XML version of the plan to reflect that shown in your image? The XML version only has two statements - neither of which are the slow UPDATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shall I kill this process and start over

Yes. The most pressing problem is your join predicate `T.RepID = T.RepID`. This means the query won't be doing what you hoped.

The join condition between the `UPDATE` target and `#temp` table is left completely uncorrelated.

The execution plan image shows that SQL Server treated it as below

```
UPDATE T
SET    RepType = @RT
FROM   Tags T
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #R) R
WHERE  T.RepType IS NULL
       AND T.RepID BETWEEN @N AND @N + 2000000
```

i.e. Check if `#R` has at least one row and if it does execute the inside part of the nested loops join which gets **all** rows from `Tags` where `RepType IS NULL AND RepID BETWEEN @N AND @N + 2000000` and `UPDATE` them.

This step still took an unexpectedly long time but you say it is on Windows 10 so I assume this is some memory starved instance and the sort of the 142 million matching rows spilled to disc a lot.

When you fix the logic error you should consider adding an index to `Tags` on `RepID` so that matching rows can be found efficiently for the join (might need to include `RepType` in it if the execution plan doesn't use it).

Comment: Nice catch.. I missed the logic error entirely.

Comment: OMG... i did not see that coming.. nice catch. 24 hours wasted of my time

Comment: The "won't be doing the desired operation" bit is the key bit - it looks like SQL Server optimiser figured out that it just needed to verify that at least one row exists in `#R` and added a `TOP 1` to the plan so the cartesian join blowing up rows is **not** the issue - but still it is updating every row in `Tags` matching `T.RepType is null and T.RepID between @N and @N+2000000` without reference to the contents of `#R` - which is not what was intended.  This is certainly also slower than I would have expected but probably a blessing in this case as gave you a chance to cancel